# Not sure file is being read: Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So I have been having an interesting time trying to get Stripe up and running in my app, currently the problem is that a payment token is not being generated for transactions. When I try to process a test payment I get this error: `Must provide source or customer.`

Inside of console I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined`

I think the problem is that the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>` file is not being read, as it is what should be giving me my token. I have been at this for quite some time, and have read everything I could get my hands on online, but haven't found a solution that works for me yet. It is probably something small, and any help is really really appreciated.

Here is my controller:

```
require "stripe"
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

        def new
            @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        end

        def create
            binding.pry

            @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
            Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_JlKC4V7nmCQ0sE4iNAVyoAxA"

            #Get the credit card details submitted by the form
            token = params[:stripeToken]

              # Amount in cents, this is being read and recorded in stripe dashboard
               amount = (params[:amount].to_f * 100).to_i

              charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                    :amount      => amount,
                    :source      => token,
                    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                    :currency    => 'usd'
              )

            rescue Stripe::CardError => e
              flash[:error] = e.message

                #save what we need for our server as a new payment 
                binding.pry 
                @payment = Payment.create({
                    user_id: current_user.id,
                    project_id: @project.id,
                    amount: @amount,
                    comments: params[:comments]
                    })
                #make a function in payments model that will convert the cents back into dollars
                @project.addMoney(@amount) #add it to project
                @payment.save

            end

        private
        def charges_params
            params.require(:payment).permit(:comments, :user_id, :project_id, :amount)
        end
end
```

I am not creating a customer, as I was explicitly told by Stripe support via email, that I need not if I am only processing one-time payments, which I am. Here is the payment form, which includes the Javascript in the head (as per Stripe's example):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">

 // The required Stripe lib 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script> 

<script>
   Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= ENV['SECRET_KEY'] %>');

      function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        if (response.error) {
            // Show the errors on the form
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
            var token = response.id;
            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
            // and submit
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
      }

      $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);
            alert('you clicked submit');
            console.log('this function was hit');
          // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
          $form.find('submit').prop('disabled', true);
          Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

          // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
          return false;
        });

  </script>
</head>

<!--  form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row Row one">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
        <h1>Make your contribution</h1>
           <%= form_for @project, url: project_charges_path, :html => {:id => "payment-form"}, method: 'post' do |f| %>

                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :@project_id, :value => @project.id %>


                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code (cvc)" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Expiration" %>
                  <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
                  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}%>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :amount, "Amount" %><br>
                    <%= text_field_tag :amount, nil,  name: nil, class: 'form-control', :required => true %> 
                </div> 

                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :comments, "Add a comment?" %><br>
                    <%= text_area_tag :comments, nil,  name: nil,  class: 'form-control', :required => true %> 
                </div>                

                <div class= "actions">
                  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'contribution-submit' %>
                </div>

          <div id="stripe_error">
              <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
          </div>

          <% end %> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row"></div> -->
</div>
```

Another thing I find odd that may be worth mentioning in case it is indicative of what the problem may be - the files in this view folder (where the form lives) are not picking up any of the sites css which is provided in the application.html.erb. That is why I had to manually include it in the head of the form's html.erb, as well as include the `js.stripe.com` file. The css is now rendering, but this file does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: The JavaScript error says that Stripe is not defined, which line of Your JavaScript code is it referring to? My guess is the line that calls setPublishableKey(), because you need to wait for the script to finish loading before you try to use Stripe.

Comment: it is pointing to this line: ` Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= ENV['SECRET_KEY'] %>');` so you were right on. Should I put this in an onload?

Comment: putting it in a onload didn't help

Answer (score 1):

not sure what did it exactly, but went back and copied Stripes code again and it now works. My form now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Contribution Form</title>

  <!-- The required Stripe lib -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= 'pk_test_KfCg1YmVXwBYyEdPEWnfibF8'%>');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()}, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--  form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row Row one">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
        <h1>Make your contribution</h1>
           <%= form_for @project, url: project_charges_path, :html => {:id => "payment-form"}, method: 'post' do |f| %>

                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :@project_id, :value => @project.id %>


                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: ' card-number form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code (cvc)" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'card-cvc form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Expiration" %>
                  <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, class: "card-expiry-month"} %>
                  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, class: "card-expiry-year"}%>
                </div>


                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :amount, "Amount" %><br>
                    <%= text_field_tag :amount %> 
                </div> 

                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :comments, "Add a comment?" %><br>
                    <%= text_area_tag :comments %> 
                </div>                 

                <div class= "actions">
                  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'contribution-submit' %>
                </div>

          <div id="stripe_error">
              <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
          </div>

          <% end %> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row"></div> -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```